# What credentials are sent when an XHR specifies withCredentials?

Tags: oauth

I have an OAuth client that is retrieving an access token successfully.
However, when I send out an XHR, I still need to manually construct the Authorization header, despite specifying withCredentials:true.
I'm assuming that typically the OAuth client would write the credentials somewhere where the browser can access and use them on subsequent requests and perhaps it's not doing that. If that is true, what could I be missing here? Can someone point to some sample code in an OAuth client that is responsible for storing the token in a manner that is accessible to the browser using withCredentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Unfortunately, Browser support HTTP authentication hasn't really progressed since 1997, and we're still manually adding Authorization headers, can't access OAuth2 protected endpoints directly with a browser or have a way to log out from the browser chrome.

You need to add the header yourself.

What `withCredentials` does control is automatically sending `Authorization` headers for places you are already logged in, but only for `Basic` and `Digest` auth, and it can also control sending cookies automatically or not.

Plug, but on-topic: I wrote a `fetch()` wrapper that can add the header transparently: [fetch-mw-oauth2](https://github.com/evert/fetch-mw-oauth2). If you don't like the project, you can still check it out for sample code.